# Calling FFMPEG commands from xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ffmpeg

i have got some library files of FFMPEG:

libavcodec.a
libavfilter.a
libavutil.a
libswscale.a
libavdevice.a
libavformat.a
libswresample.a

Can anybody tell me how to use these libraries if i want to do audio conversion of amr file to mp3 in iphone app.

The amr file is placed in resource bundle

I cannot understand how to call the methods of the library for audio format conversion.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: From Xcode? I don't think you can alter Xcode to randomly call libffmpeg. Didn't you mean calling it from your iPhone app?

Comment: Can you do the transcoding(amr to mp3) on the server side?

Comment: ofcourse i need to call ffmpeg from my iphone app...I have to do this from my iphone app for certain reasons so server side is not involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're only doing audio conversion, you may want to look into a library called core-amr.

Comment: i downloaded opencore-amr, compiled it for simulator + device and added the .a "libopencore-amrnb.a" and "libopencore-amrwb.a" file in my project and have set the search path also. I can now include header files but now i am not sure how to utilize the methods to do the conversion

Comment: Never actually used it myself, I think of amr on the iphone as a non starter but I did find this once http://blog.csdn.net/favormm/article/details/6804553 which seems to explain how to use it

Comment: thank u so much, i found a similar link here : http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/pkg-multimedia-commits/2009-September/003381.html -------- but now the problem is that data is written on the output file but when i play file it shows duration as 00:00

Comment: hey, the links helped me in creating output file but when app is run on simulator the output file is perfect but when i test on device then output file contains only Noise..... what to do....any help is appreciated :)

Comment: is it possible you didn't build armv7 versions of the lib

Comment: no the app runs on the device but noise reduction was done when i changed the values in writeHeader from 16 to 20, its working now